# smartgwt beginner- getting eclipse error when i try to create a project containing a sample from the smartgwt showcase

Tags: smartgwt

I am trying to create one of the drag and drop samples given in showcase--

The sample is at http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#effects_dd_copy_list

For the following line of code I am getting an error in Eclipse--

final PartsListGrid myList1 = new PartsListGrid();

The error is "PartsListGrid cannot be resolved to a type"

I think there is an import statement missing- how do I resolve the above error?

Thanks,
Arvind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PartListGrid is not a class from the SmartGWt framework but a specific class of the show case which is derived from ListGrid.
You can either make your own or use a ListGrid and set some properties .
Have a look [there](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/smartgwt/sample/showcase/client/effects/dragdrop/PartsListGrid.java?r=1067).